# Using a map in a fragment in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I have a fragment activity in one fragment has a few textfields and a mapview.The second fragment has a textfield which shows news items.The first fragment has the map inside a fragment.So this is a case of nested fragments.

The fragment activity is :

```
package com.igloo.collegefinder;




import com.igloo.classes.College_data;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class FragmentMain extends FragmentActivity {
    LinearLayout footer;
    Button btndetails,btncollegenews;
    College_data college_item;
    Fragment fr;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        footer=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer);
        btndetails=(Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btndetails);
        btncollegenews=(Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btncollegenews);
        college_item= (College_data) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("college_data");

//      Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("college_data",college_item);

        final CollegeDetails fragobj1=new CollegeDetails();
        fragobj1.setArguments(bundle);

        final NewsDetails fragobj2=new NewsDetails();
        fragobj2.setArguments(bundle);

        fr=fragobj1;
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
         android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fr);      
         fragmentTransaction.commit();

         btndetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                fr=new CollegeDetails();
                fr.setArguments(bundle);
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fr);      
                 fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });
         btncollegenews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fr=new NewsDetails();
                fr.setArguments(bundle);
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fr);      
                 fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });


    }


}
```

The first fragment is:

```
package com.igloo.collegefinder;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.igloo.classes.College_data;
import com.igloo.classes.News_data;
import com.igloo.collegefinder.CollegeMain.RetrieveColleges;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CollegeDetails extends Fragment {

    TextView txtcollegename,txtcollegeaddress,txtcollegepho,txtcollegelatitude,txtcollegelongitude,txtcollegeimage,txtcollegenews;
    String college_name,course_name;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String URL="http://footballultimate.com/finder/index.php/api/collegeDataWithoutFilter";
    HttpResponse response;
    String result,news_value="";
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray college_data;
    College_data college_item;
    Bundle b;
    View v;
    FragmentManager fragManager;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
     // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //setContentView(R.layout.college_details);
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.college_details, null, false);
        txtcollegename=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtcollegename);
        txtcollegeaddress=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtcollegeaddress);
        txtcollegepho=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegepho);
        txtcollegelatitude=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegelatitude);
        txtcollegelongitude=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegelongitude);
        txtcollegeimage=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegeimage);
        txtcollegenews=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegenews);
        //college_item= (College_data)getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("college_data");
        college_item=(College_data) getArguments().getSerializable("college_data");


        txtcollegename.setText(college_item.collegename);
        txtcollegeaddress.setText(college_item.collegeaddress);
        txtcollegepho.setText(college_item.collegephone);
        txtcollegelatitude.setText(college_item.collegelatitude);
        txtcollegelongitude.setText(college_item.collegelongitude);
        txtcollegeimage.setText(college_item.collegeimage);
//      for(News_data item : college_item.news_list){
//          news_value=news_value+item.news+" ";
//      }
//      txtcollegenews.setText(news_value);
         try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
         myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
            super.onAttach(activity);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
             fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
            googleMap = ( (SupportMapFragment) fragManager.findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();


            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
         // latitude and longitude
            double latitude =Double.parseDouble(college_item.collegelatitude);
            double longitude =Double.parseDouble(college_item.collegelongitude);

            // create marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(college_item.collegename);
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            // adding marker
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);




           // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);





            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),12.0f));

            }
        }
}
     @Override
    public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            initilizeMap();
        }

}
```

The xml file for the first fragment is:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtcollegename"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtcollegeaddress"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtcollegepho"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtcollegelatitude"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtcollegelongitude"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtcollegeimage"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtcollegenews"
        />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The second fragment is :

```
package com.igloo.collegefinder;

import com.igloo.classes.College_data;
import com.igloo.classes.News_data;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewsDetails extends Fragment {
    View v;
    TextView txtnewsfinal;
    College_data college_item;
    String news_value="";
    @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
          ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_details, null, false);
        college_item=(College_data) getArguments().getSerializable("college_data");

        txtnewsfinal=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtnewsfinal);
        for(News_data item : college_item.news_list){
            news_value=news_value+item.news+" ";
        }
        txtnewsfinal.setText(news_value);


        return v;
    }
    }
```

The second xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txtnewsfinal"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is the following:

**When the fragment main loads the world map is shown in the background , then the required map is shown below.This is because of the class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" in fragment_main.xml**

**When i go to the second fragment , the news items are shown.But when i click the button of the first fragment,the applicaion force closes with the following LOGCAT:**

```
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class fragment
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at com.igloo.collegefinder.CollegeDetails.onCreateView(CollegeDetails.java:65)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #43: Duplicate id 0x7f06001e, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
07-14 13:58:15.906: E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    ... 19 more
```

It shows that the class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" element is duplicate.Which is because the fragment activity and the first fragment has the same name.But without it the fragment activity doesnt function.Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Because of this sort of things it is a good practice to add all your fragments programatically using a **FragmentManager** and a **FrameLayout** just as you did for your first Activity.

The only difference is that to use nested Fragments you need to call **getChildFragmentManager** in your parent Fragment insted of **getFragmentManager** .

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();    
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();     
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_container, mapFragment);      
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: you have used replace method to add mapfragment , but my fragment class contains other elements too besides the map.Will it work??

Comment: The method getChildFragmentManager is undefined error!!

Comment: Yes, just replace your <fragment> element in your layout with a <FrameLayout>

Comment: Do you mean to change fragment to framelayout in the fragment main class or in the class having the map??

Comment: In your first fragment:  <fragment android:id="@+id/map">.

Comment: The first problem is solved , that is there are no two maps.But when i click the button for college details again i get the following error:07-14 14:24:26.851: E/AndroidRuntime(11061):  at com.igloo.collegefinder.CollegeDetails.initilizeMap(CollegeDetails.java:111)
07-14 14:26:54.351: E/AndroidRuntime(11249): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #43: Duplicate id 0x7f06001e, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: are you sure you don't have repeated ids? and you need to remove android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" from your (now) FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

You have to destroy the GoogleMap correctly, or you will get this exception.
Override this Method in your Map-Fragment and it should work:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() 
     {
        super.onDestroyView(); 
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```